# How to understand the code flow in nuxeo

Tags: eclipse, nuxeo

Recently I have downloaded the Nuxeo code, SDK and Nuxio IDE for the development purpose. I am also able to do build the project run the SDK and importing project into eclipse. But as Nuxeo guys know, it's a huge project and document doesn't contains details about the Code Flow. So, I am sucked. To develop and fix bugs I need to know the existing code structure, functionality of each projects(modules/bundles) , how to identify the code flow if user click on a button. So, please help me

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the UI you want to debug. If it's the JSF UI, then the buttons are usually associated with an "action" contributed from an XML file. You can then follow the thread.

Your question is too much generic to give you more details. Do look for development guidelines and/or how-to fix some bugs? In the latter case, it depends on each kind of bug, the Nuxeo version, the original code writer (Nuxeo legacy code or customized code), the use of Nuxeo Studio or not...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also heard that it's possible to block a particular feature in nuxeo by changing some configuration files in server. SO, could you tell me which configuration file.

Comment: Again, that depends on which feature: almost everything in Nuxeo can be customized with "contributions" and "extension-points" (see [NXDOC/How+to+Contribute+to+an+Extension][1]). For instance, you could deactivate a feature, or remove its button, or make its availability depend on some criteria (often the user group).


  [1]: http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/iw7F

Comment: Actually I am very new to the Nuxeo. Thats why. My task is to find how to block or disable functionality in Nuxeo 6. And in this big project I am bit confused. So, is there any